Is there a symmetry related to conservation of kinetic energy?
Per Noether's theorem, time-translational symmetry leads to energy conservation. This identity works for any system not just free particles. However one could consider a dynamical system (breaking time-translation) but where kinetic energy remains the same. What would be the symmetry here? Any guide on how to reverse Noether theorem would help or any indication on why there is no such a symmetry.
From Is the converse of Noether's first theorem true: Every conservation law has a symmetry? I can work out that action has to be invariant to the transformation $q\to q+p \epsilon$ where $q$ is the position and $p$ the momentum and $\epsilon$ is small. Does this transformation have any meaning?

"However one could consider a dynamical system (breaking time-translation) but where kinetic energy remains the same." -- Have you actually imagined this system? Like, actually written down a Lagrangian/Hamiltonian/equation of motion and shown it had this property?

@Andrew no because I am struggling to see how it could be possible because all examples I have are when energy and kinetic energy are conserved. One could imagine a forced spring-like system that tries to keep the mass in the spring going at the same absolute-value of the speed even when the mass shrinks or expands the springs. The hard part is not to make that force speed dependent.

Yeah so, I might challenge the framework of your question. I think what you're getting at is that logically, a statement and its converse are independent. So Noether's theorem as it's usually presented -- "symmetry implies conservation law" -- does not rule out a conservation law existing without a symmetry. But I don't think you're going to have a lot of luck constructing a system with something like energy conservation without a principle guaranteeing it is there, because conservation laws are kind of special and "shouldn't" happen unless there's some reason they have to be there. (...)

(...) On top of that, the relationship between symmetries and conservation laws is a bit deeper. Within Hamiltonian mechanics, the conservation laws act as generators for a symmetry group using Poisson brackets. Now there are questions here about the inverse Noether theorem, and it is a subtle story, but gets very technical. A zeroth order physics answer is that conservation laws are inevitably tied to symmetries.

@Andrew thanks for you comment I agree, I am just trying to find a compelling argument. However if I understand the link that you posted it seems it is possible to create such a generator, it seems to follow from making a differential change such that $\delta x=p\epsilon$ remains the same.

I will consider autonomous systems. Noether’s theorem is easier in the Hamiltonian setting. Let $H$ be the Hamiltonian on a $2n$ dimensional phase space with canonical coordinates $x_i,p_i$ and $K$ the kinetic energy:
$$
K=\sum \frac12p_i^2
$$
Conservation of energy means that in terms of Poisson brackets:
$$
\{H,K\}=0
$$
This means that $H$ is invariant by the symmetry generated by $K$:
$$
\dot x_i=\{x_i,K\}=p_i \quad \dot p_i=\{p_i,K\}=0
$$
i.e. it is invariant by your transvections:
$$
x_i\to x_i+p_is\quad p_i\to p_i
$$
Physically, this symmetry is just ballistic motion. Thus your Hamiltonian is invariant by ballistic motion:
$$
H(x_i,p_i) = H(x_i+sp_i,p_i)
$$
It is not hard to find all of such systems. A simple way is choose a transverse hypersurface to the flow lines. A suitable candidate is the hyperplane:
$$
\sum x_i\frac{p_i}{\sqrt{2K}}=0
$$
Thus such Hamiltonians are of the form for any function $h$ defined on the hyperplane:
$$
H=h\left(x_i-p_i\sum_j x_j\frac{p_j}{\sqrt{2K}},p_i\right)
$$
Geometrically, this means that $H$ is a function of $p$ and the normal components of $x$ to $p$.
For physical applications, this is rarely the case. In non relativistic mechanics, you typically have $H = K+V$ with $V$ a position dependent potential. The only $V$ compatible with this symmetry is a constant, so conservation of kinetic energy in this case is trivial since it is just the Hamiltonian. Even adding magnetism will not help.

Thanks that's what I was looking for. Could you expand a bit more on the interpretation? what you mean by " mist be invariant by ballistic motion" ? How does this fit to an example?

I am not sure about the last comment you added about the potential being a constant and magnetism not helping. Here are some other cases (1) a translationally invariant potential (2) $V$ being some constraint like a ball bouncing between two parallel walls  (3) a charged particle in a magnetic field, the particle moves in circular orbits keeping its kinetic energy constant

In all your examples, kinetic energy is conserved because it is the total Hamiltonian. In this sense, they are not interesting or new. Actually, your third example does not even work because it is the gauge invariant kinetic energy $K = \frac12\sum\dot x^2$ which is conserved, not the canonical $K = \frac12\sum p^2$

I agree but why is this still not considered another symmetry of the system? Can you show (gauge-invariant) kinetic energy is conserved under this symmetry?
